# The file routing.yml not work anymore

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, routes

I wrote in my routing.yml file two patterns for two url, but my symfony 2.8.2 generated next error: "The file C:\xampp...routing.yml does not contain valid YAML ...". This code worked in symfony 2.0.0 but not work anymore in 2.8.2. Can anyone tell me way?

```
demo_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: DemoBundle:Default:index }

demo_hello:
    path:     /hello
    defaults: { _controller: DemoBundle:Default:hello }
```

Comment: is that all there is in the file? looks ok to me.  [YamlLint](http://www.yamllint.com/) doesnt like that youve not quoted your values for your controllers.  But Id be surprised if it was that.

Comment: Make sure you use spaces, not tabs in your YAML file. The YAML you pasted here is fine.

Comment: My advice, use annotations.

Comment: Going from 2.0 to 2.8 is quite a jump.  Might consider going to 2.1 first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file looks fine, perhaps problem not with them... Check your `config.yml`

```
framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
```

Pay attention for `config_dev.yml` should be selected `routing_dev.yml`.